# Blazor equivalent to Angular's composite styles?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm migrating a project from Angular to Blazor (.NET 6 rc2), and I'm curious whether Blazor has a similar composite style ability.

In Angular, you can bind values to parts of a `style` string, and the string will be constructed at runtime. e.g.

```
<div [style.padding-bottom.%]="displayAspectRatio">
</div>
```

Would read my code property `displayAspectRatio` and compose it into the element's style string, e.g. `style="padding-bottom: 32.8%;"`

I'll always use classes where possible, but in those special situations where the styles must be calculated on a per-element basis, what's the best practice in Blazor currently?

In Blazor .NET6 is it still;

```
<div style="@($"padding-bottom: {displayAspectRatio}%")">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing directly equivalent. The only way to do it is the way you have mentioned. However, You can use attribute splatting or arbitrary parameters if there are too many attributes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters-1